# How to assign a tensor in Tensorflow like Pytorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to convert a Pytorch script into a Tensorflow script. But I am unable to assign a tensor in tensorflow like pytorch.

**Code:**

```
import torch
import tensorflow as tf


def true_positive(pred, target, num_classes): #number of classes
    out = []
    for i in range(num_classes):
        out.append(((pred == i) & (target == i)).sum())

    return torch.tensor(out)
```

**Pytorch implementation:** Working

```
p = torch.tensor([1]) 
t = torch.tensor([2])
n = torch.tensor([2])
y = true_positive(p,t,n)
```

**Tensorflow implementation:** Not working!

```
p = tf.constant([1]) #c = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
t = tf.constant([2])
n = tf.constant([2])
y = true_positive(p,t,n)
```

**Error :**

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [18], in <cell line: 22>()
> 20 t = tf.constant([2])
> 21 n = tf.constant([2])
> ---> 22 y = true_positive(p,t,n)
>
> Input In [18], in true_positive(pred, target, num_classes)
> 5 def true_positive(pred, target, num_classes): #number of classes
> 6     out = []
> ----> 7     for i in range(num_classes):
> 8         out.append(((pred == i) & (target == i)).sum())
> 10     return torch.tensor(out)
>
> File
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1131,
> in _EagerTensorBase.**index**(self)    1130 def **index**(self):
> -> 1131   return self._numpy().**index**()
>
> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
> index

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to `sum` ?

Comment: I am actually trying to convert a pytorch script into tensorflow and hence I am also confused on that part, the original paper is in Pytorch and the source code is : https://github.com/seongjunyun/Graph_Transformer_Networks/blob/master/utils.py , I have posted one of the method from this utils module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf


def true_positive(pred, target, num_classes): #number of classes
    out = []
    for i in tf.range(num_classes):
      out.append(tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast((pred == i) & (target == i), dtype=tf.int32)))
    return tf.stack(out)

p = tf.constant([4]) #c = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
t = tf.constant([4])
n = tf.constant([4])
y = true_positive(p,t,n)
y
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: Yes, this works fine. But I am still confused that, the Pytorch code gives the answer as `tensor([0, 0, 0, 0])` and yours gives as `<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)>` . Although I understand they both mean the same! Will it be better if I present the results after converting them into a numpy array (for both Pytorch and TF )?